# Remote Command executed via ssh does not return proper return code. Return error code is always "0", even condition failed

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting, exit-status

I am not getting proper exit return code during execution of remote script on a Linux machine.
This script is intended for checking whether a user exists or not.

My Script is below :-

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date "+%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S"`
for i in `cat /home/sandeep/server_ip_list/serverlist_New`
do 
     ipaddress=${i}
     echo -e "\n***************" >> /tmp/userfind_${DATE}.txt
     echo -e "$ipaddress" >> /tmp/userfind_${DATE}.txt
     for b in `cat /home/sandeep/Project_finduser01/userslist`
     do     
         userid=${b}
         echo -e "\n" >> /tmp/userfind_${DATE}.txt
         echo -n "$userid" >> /tmp/userfind_${DATE}.txt
         ssh -t sandeep@${ipaddress} "grep $userid /etc/passwd > /dev/null;
         if [ "$?" = "0" ];  
         then
             echo -n " : User exsits"
         else
             echo -n " : User not exsits"
         fi" >> /tmp/userfind_${DATE}.txt 
done 
done
```

---

I am always getting the output below, whether the user exists or not:

```
***************
10.25.59.12


sandeepj: User exsits

pravin: User exsits

ram: User exsits

sita: User exsits

raj.singh: User exsits
```

How to manipulate remote exit status codes at server side?

Comment: You are using double quoted strings within double quoted strings (see `"$?"` and the other things that you quote within the command you execute with `ssh`).

Comment: I removed "" from $? but still same output. + for b in '`cat /home/sandeepj/Project_finduser01/userslist`'
+ userid=raj.singh
+ echo -e '\n'
+ echo -n raj.singh
+ ssh -t sandeepj@10.25.59.2 'grep raj.singh /etc/passwd > /dev/null;
 if [ 0 = 0 ];
 then
 echo -n ' : User 'exsits
 > /tmp/status
 else
 echo -n ' : User not 'exsits
 > /tmp/status
 fi'

Comment: I this really your script? If you run what you show, you will get syntax errors because of the wrong quotes. You need a closing `"` on the `grep` line, and you have an extra `"` on the final `fi` line. Look at the syntax highlighting (colors) in your question. Please [edit] and fix it so you show the _exact_ script you are running.

Comment: @terdon - Script is working fine and i am using same " "  to pass my multiple command with ssh.it will be very help full if you guide me any idea or alternate  about this code. I am beginner in Shell Scripting track.

Comment: @SandeepSingh if the script is working, then you are not running the script you have in your question. Please correct the issues I mentioned in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applied suggested changes if find two ways to achieve my result.

**First Solution :** Using for Loop

```
#!/bin/bash/expect
DATE=`date "+%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S"`
for i in `cat /root/project_finduser/serverlist`;
do
        echo -e "\n*******************" 
        echo -e "$i" 
           for a in `cat /root/project_finduser/userslist`;
           do
             echo -e "\n" 
             echo -n "$a :" 
           if ssh "root@${i}" cat /etc/passwd | grep -w -q -F -e "$a";
           then
             echo "User exsits"
           else
             echo "User not exsits"
           fi 
done 
done >>"/tmp/userfind_${DATE}.txt"
```

**Second Solution :** Using While loop  { I have passed -n option with ssh command becuase while loop stop reading argument from file after first line}

```
    #!/bin/bash
    DATE=`date "+%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S"`
    while IFS= read -r ipaddress;
    do
          echo -e "\n*******************"
          echo -e "$ipaddress"
               while IFS= read -r userid;
               do
                    echo -e "\n"
                    echo -n "$userid : "
               if ssh -n "root@${ipaddress}" getent passwd "$userid" >/dev/null;
               then
                    echo -n "User exsits"
               else
                    echo -n "User not exsits"
               fi 
done < /root/project_finduser/userslist
done < /root/project_finduser/serverlist  >"/tmp/userfind_${DATE}.txt"
```

**Output :**

---

192.168.56.103

sandeep : User exsits

student : User exsits

ram  : User not exsits

sita : User not exsits

swati : User exsits

student : User exsits

---

192.168.56.104

sandeep : User not exsits

student : User exsits

ram  : User not exsits

sita : User not exsits

swati : User not exsits

student : User exsits

Comment: I am not sure as an admin or security auditor I would like to see a connection hammering situation like this. Why not use an array to hold all of them in one connection? `users=( $(ssh user@host ‘getent passwd’) )` then pluck out those you expect to exist? `echo ${users[@]} | tr ‘ ‘ ‘\n’ | egrep ‘user1|user2’`

Comment: Thanks Jas - For your Suggestion,I think you right. Array help in to close this in one connection only.

Answer (score 4):

The main issue in your code is that `$?` is expanded before `ssh` is called. This is due to quoting.  All expansions in a double-quoted string are expanded before the string is used.  In addition to that, the double-quoted string that you are using with `ssh` contains other double-quoted sections.  These sections would be *unquoted*, just like the substring `abc` is unquoted in `"123"abc"456"`.

---

Instead of trying to execute a complicated command on the remote host, just let the `ssh` command `cat` the `passwd` file, then `grep` that:

```
if ssh -n "sandeep@$ipaddress" cat /etc/passwd | grep -q -F -e "$userid"
then
    echo "User exists"
else
    echo "User does not exist"
fi >>"/tmp/userfind_$DATE.txt"
```

Also, consider reading from the user and server list using a while loop instead:

```
while IFS= read -r userid; do
   # ...
done </home/sandeep/Project_finduser01/userslist
```

You may also redirect the outermost loop to your output file instead of redirecting every single `echo`:

```
while ...; do
    while ...; do
       # stuff
    done <userlist
done <serverlist  >"/tmp/userfind_$DATE.txt"
```

If your user list is long, you may want to only get the `passwd` from the remote host once, and then query that several times

```
while ...; do
    scp "sandeep@$ipaddress:/etc/passwd" passwd.tmp
    while ...; do
       if grep -q -F -e "$userid" passwd.tmp; then
          # exists
       fi
    done <userlist
done <serverlist  >"/tmp/userfind_$DATE.txt"
```

Even more efficiently would be to read the user list into an `awk` array and then match the usernames from the `passwd` file against them.  That would get rid of the innermost loop entirely.

The username is found in a *particular* field in the `passwd` file.  With your approach, you would match both `marc` and `marco` if you searched for `marc`.  To match a bit more carefully, consider using a pattern such as `"^$userid:"` instead of matching against the whole line (and drop the `-F` that I introduced above if you're still using `grep` to do this).

You may also avoid the parsing of the `passwd` file completely with

```
getent passwd "$userid" >/dev/null
```

This returns a zero exit code (success) if the user exists and non-zero otherwise.

I.e.,

```
if ssh -n "sandeep@$ipaddress" getent passwd "$userid" >/dev/null
then
    # exists
else
    # does not exist
fi
```

This would do one `ssh` call against the remote host per user though.  This could be made a bit more efficient by not closing the connection between each call (the below would keep the connection open for one minute):

```
if ssh -n -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=1m "sandeep@$ipaddress" getent passwd "$userid" >/dev/null
then
    # exists
else
    # does not exist
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @kusalananda - For your valuable inputs. I will try these options and keep you update.

Answer (score 0):

Why not capture the result code from `$?` like so…

`ssh user@host 'cmd arg;echo $?'`

If you assign that to a variable you can then use a `[ $n -gt 0 ]` test against it.

Comment: Why echo the exit code at all?  The exit code of `ssh` will be the exit code of the command.

Comment: I tried this ssh user@host ' cmd $arg; if [ $? -eq 0 ] but its doesn't work in, condition of local argument passed to remote ssh command. $? Value in if condition always come null.